# My leopard gecko arm was taken off by my sister's cat while was at work!

Tags: safety, reptiles, leopard-geckos, geckos

I was at work and my door was closed.  My sister opened the door and the cat got in and was pawing at it. The cat broke open the roof and attacked gecko's tail and took his leg clean off! What kind of first aid should I do?

Comment: If taking the gecko to a vet is an option, that should be your first choice as soon as possible. I am not gecko expert so can't offer more but hopefully one will be by soon.

Comment: Maybe clean and apply antibiotics to open wounds.  If the leg is clean off and tail is not bleeding then the gecko has made it past the initial trauma.   It still may be life threatening.  A vet will be able to give you better analysis and long term care but not sure an emergency Sunday clinic can do a lot in the short term.

Comment: Second thing I'd do is fix whatever mistake was made that allowed the cat to reach the gecko.

Comment: Use paper towels for a substrate, and take it to the vet, period.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a big wound, like that seems to be, I would use neosporin and some clean gauze or cloth to try to stop the bleeding. Neosporin is safe to use on beardies and snakes, so I assume it is for them too. You will probably want to try drying the wound after you have cleaned it, and take it to the vet as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens in the future then if the tail was dropped and not bitten which they generally are then it will be fine but for the leg clean it and call the vet to ask about the next step hope this helps!